# How to append rows in QuestDB using embedded API?

Tags: questdb

I am looking for an example of how to use QuestDB embedded in Java process. I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE market_tick ( tickTimeStamp TIMESTAMP, token SYMBOL) 
timestamp(tickTimeStamp) 
PARTITION BY MONTH
```

and I append rows like

```
TableWriter tableWriter = questDB.getTableWrite( "market_tick" ) ;
TableWriter.Row row = tableWriter.newRow() ;
row.putTimestamp( 0, timeStamp );
String token = String.valueOf(event.getToken()) ;
row.putSym(1, token );
tableWriter.commit();
```

and I have exception

```
io.questdb.cairo.CairoException: [5] Cannot remove directory: C:\trade\questdb\market_tick\1970-01\token.k
    at io.questdb.std.ThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:36)
    at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:172)
    at io.questdb.cairo.CairoException.instance(CairoException.java:42)
```

How to insert rows using Java embedded API?

Answer (score 0):

Since the table `market_tick` has designated timestamp, you cannot use `tableWriter.newRow()` to create new row but have to use `tableWriter.newRow(timeStamp)`. The rest of the code is correct

```
TableWriter tableWriter = questDB.getTableWrite( "market_tick" ) ;
TableWriter.Row row = tableWriter.newRow(timeStampMicroSeconds) ;
String token = String.valueOf(event.getToken()) ;
row.putSym(1, token );
tableWriter.commit();
```